# MediaElementJS very buggy

Tags: javascript, html, video

Ive implemented an instance of mediaelement.js for my videos which are all in mp4 format. I cant get it to work properly, however. First here is how I have implemented it:

Video:

```
<video src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls preload="none" width="500" height="282"></video>
```

Place at the end of the body, right after including mediaelement.js itself:

```
$("video").mediaelementplayer({
  mode:"shim",
  startVolume:0.3
 });
```

The problems I am having are:

- In IE the silverlight player wont play the media. It looks like it is being loaded, since the videos length is being shown.
- When mode is set to "shim," Chrome doesnt allow fullscreen.
- When mode is set to "shim," iPhone users are met by a dead link.
- When mode isnt set to "shim," iPhone users are met by the player that wont play the video.

Videos are .mp4 and in h.264 encoding.

Thanks in advance for any attempt to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the videos had been interlaced by the media encoder. IE+iPhones dont play those.

The fullscreen was a problem with the flashplayer and only happened in some versions of Chrome.